# Xcode 7.3.1 fails when compiling sources (Cocoapods)

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Im pulling my hair out over this. Ive made a duplicate of my an Xcode project and I then went and renamed the target, folders within the project, build config and basically removed every reference to the old project. I then used `pod deintegrate` to remove cocoa pods completely. As well as deleting the master repo.

I then did a pod install but when it gets to compiling sources it fails, and the only errors that are coming up are those from my project that are basically being caused from the missing header files.

Ive checked my framework and library paths and they both use `$(inherited)`

Any suggestions would really be appreciated, Ive already wasted 2 days on this.

[image: Errors]

EDIT: I've noticed that my libPod-ProjectName.a is red and isn't being created in derived data, not sure what to make of it

Comment: You need to share more about the specific errors Xcode is showing you.

Comment: Like I say, the errors are only from the missing cocoapod libraries. There are no other indications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Is the AFHTTPREQUESTSERIALIZER available ?, it seems to be deprecated so there are no results matching]

Is the AFHTTPREQUESTSERIALIZER available ?, it seems to be deprecated so there are no results matching. Confirm you are using the latest version and the framework is not longer deprecated. Please explain your problem with more information.

Alternatively, you can refer this link:-
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html

Screenshot taken from above link:-[image]

Comment: Unfortunately Ive been through those with no luck. Nothing is deprecated as Im using it in another clone of the project and have no issues.